# How to implement gimp like highlights and white point adjustment functionality using opencv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, opencv

Gimp is a famous open source image editor. Is there any way to implement this **gimp** like highlights and white point adjustment functionality using OpenCV. I'm currently working on an image manipulation project. And, want to implement this functionality in my projects. I researched everything that is available on the internet but nothing actually works for me.

Specifically, I want to add a slider functionality that will adjust image highlights and white point adjustment.

As per the documentation in gimp:-

https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-filter-shadows-highlights.html

**High Lights Adjustment**  This slider controls the effect on highlights; negative values will darken highlights while positive values will lighten them up.

**White Point Adjustment** By default the algorithm of this modules leaves black point and white point untouched. In some cases an image might contain tonal variations beyond the white point, i.e. above a luminance value of 100. A negative shift in the white point adjustment slider allows to bring these values down into the proper range so that further details in the highlights get visible.

I want this same effect that gimp uses in this slider.
Please help me to find

[image: Gimpp ScreenShot]

Comment: what do you mean by white point adjustment? you can add trackbar to opencv easily.

Comment: How to increase or decrease white point in image... is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is `gmipp` please? Do you have a link? And `gimpp`?

Comment: Gimp is a open source image editor. I also updated my post. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

There is a not-so-equal but nice implementation of this functionality [here](https://gist.github.com/HViktorTsoi/8e8b0468a9fb07842669aa368382a7df). I could use it successfully to code the same gimp functionality, in spite there are some color field transformation that may be replaced with opencv cvtColor() functions.

Have a nice day!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31031293)